# How to check if a variable entered is alphanumeric or not in ksh?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I am using ksh on AIX and I want to check if a variable, for example `var1=sanySAN`, `var2=SANYsa%$3` is alphanumeric or not.

Here, `var1` is alphanumeric and `var2` is not. I know I can use `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]` or `[:alnum:]`  but I am not sure how.

Should I check like this?

```
if [[ var == [:alnum:]* ]] 
then 
    echo "yes"
else 
    echo "no"
fi
```

I've tried many ways but they failed.

Comment: [expr](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/expr.htm) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXLY:

```
is_alnum() {
  case $1 in (*[![:alnum:]]*|"") false;; esac
}
```

Then:

```
$ is_alnum 123 && echo yes
yes
$ is_alnum % || echo no
no
```

`mksh` is the only shell failed with above approach.

---

Also note that if variable contains byte sequences that don't form valid characters, this approach won't work.

`yash` only works with valid unicode characters, so it's the only one reports error:

```
$ is_alnum $'A\xe9B'
yash: cannot convert the argument `A�B' into a wide character stringyash: the argument is replaced with an empty string
```

**Updated**

`mksh` added character classes in R56, with a bugfix in [R56c](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm#r56c).

Comment: my code has restrictions and i  am looking for a simple solution like this..                                                                                                     var="SANDY"
if [[ $var == [:alnum:]* ]] ;
then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
 but it is not working.. Whats wrong?? can you please modify it to correct code?

Comment: @santhosh: So just use `if is_alnum "$var"; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`

Comment: Note that it would return true for the empty string.

Comment: See also the `ksh93` bug mentioned in my answer which would also affect yours.

Comment: POSIX doesn't guarantee it to work if the variable may contain byte sequences that don't form valid characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks, fix for empty string. Good point about `ksh93`. Also do you have any information about `mksh`?

Comment: @cuonglm `mksh` developer here, just ask me ☺[mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm#r56c) added character classes in R56, with a bugfix in R56c, so, over three years and two weeks ago now. POSuX character classes are standards-compliant for the `C` (`POSIX`) locale. (Adding categorisation for Unicode would blow up the on-disc size of the shell by easily 30% or so, and that’s out of scope.)

Comment: @mirabilos Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Some idea based on `expr`:

```
if expr "x$string" : '.*[^[:alnum:]]' >/dev/null;
then
  printf "%s is NOT alphanumeric\n" "$string"
else
  printf "%s is alphanumeric\n" "$string"
fi
```

Note that the use of `printf` over `echo` is intentional, since `"$string"` is an arbitrary string. More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/193467). Also the "x" at the beginning prevents `expr` from choking if `$string` expands to something that starts with a `-`. My thanks to Stéphane and Sato who helped refine this answer with their comments.

Comment: That fails on `(` and some other strings that are expr operators or start with -, the list of which varies with the `expr` implementation.

Comment: Also note that `a-zA-Z` only makes sense in the C locale.

Comment: Or just `if expr "$string" : '[^[:alnum:]]' >/dev/null; then ...`

Comment: @SatoKatsura That works too, but doesn't solve the issues raised by Stéphane... Oh well, I tried !

Comment: It's about AIX `expr`.  No such problems. _shrug_

Comment: @SatoKatsura Note also that apparently you cannot go without the `.*` at the start of the regex.

Comment: Right, sorry about that, `expr` regexps are always anchored.

Comment: Use `expr " $string" : " [[:alnum:]]\{1,\}$"`

Comment: @SatoKatsura, they're anchored at the start only (implicit `^`, but not implicit `$`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas His [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/expr.htm) says that the only problem is if the string *starts* with a hyphen `-`, and the way to bypass this is given, I have updated my answer in light of your insights.

Comment: I have actually tried it with a leading hyphen in `$string`, and it still works... Beats me. Good news is, this construct seems to work even in weird cases.

Comment: Yes, AFAICT the problem with hyphens is `-<digit>`, not `-<letter>`.  Yes, `"x$string"` should work.

Comment: `.` (as in your `.*`) may not match non-characters.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, I prefer using a space character myself for those cases as it's less likely a future version of `expr` will have an operator that starts with it, and it's less likely for locales to have a collating element that contains it (IIRC, there was another less academic reason as well, but it eludes me just now).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
[[ $var = +([[:alnum:]]) ]]
```

That would work in the AT&T ksh and `zsh` implementations of `ksh`, but apparently not in `pdksh`-based ones. That works in `zsh -o kshglob` (like when `zsh` is invoked as `ksh`) or `bash -O extglob` as well.

`+(...)` is `ksh` wildcard for *one or more*. `[[:alnum:]]` is any character considered alphanumeric in the current locale (in any alphabet, not necessarily only the latin alphabet).

If you want to limit to the English letters and digits, assuming the `LC_ALL` variable is not set, you could do:

```
LC_COLLATE=C; [[ $var = +([a-zA-Z0-9]) ]]
```

If not:

```
[[ $var = +([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]) ]]
```

This:

```
LC_ALL=C; [[ $var = +([[:alnum:]]) ]]
```

Should also work even though it changes the meaning of characters. Because characters that would contain bytes that otherwise correspond to ASCII alnums (like for instance £ in GB18030 which is encoded as 81 30 84 35 where 30 also happens to be ASCII 0) would also contain bytes that are not in ASCII (like 81 84 for £), and all charsets on a given system have to agree on the encoding of the characters in the portable charset which includes all the English alphanumerics.

Also note that in UTF-8 locales, ksh93u+ (at least) currently has a bug in that if `$var` contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters, but those bytes correspond to alnums in the ISO-8859-1 character set, then they would be considered as `alnums`. For instance `$'A\xe9B'` would be considered as an alphanumeric because 0xe9 is é in ISO-8859-1. (U+00E9 is `é`, but the UTF-8 encoding of é is 0xc3 0xa9, not 0xe9).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.. after many attempts i got this solution working.

```
var=`echo "some-value" | tr -d "[:alnum:]"`
if [ "$var" == "" ]; then
echo " string has only alphanumerics"
else
echo "something other than alphanumerals  is there"
fi
```

Comment: You can't use `echo`. That would fail on things like `\0141` or `-n` depending on the `echo` variant you have. It would also fail to detect trailing newline characters. I don't know about the AIX version, but note that the GNU version works only with single-byte characters.